# How can I show the output of two print statements from two different functions on the same line?

Tags: function, if-statement, python-3.x

The code for my question is as follows:

```
def score_Calc(par, strokes, hole_number):

  if strokes == par - 1:
     print ('On hole #',hole_number, 'a par',par,'you shot a birdie.')

def score_Calcs (par, strokes, hole_number):

 if strokes == 1:
    print('with a Hole in One!')
```

My question is this: How can I get the printed results on one line? Right now, I've got it printing out as:

```
On hole # 5 a par 5 you shot 5 over par.
  with a Bo Derek. Bummer.
```

How can I get it to print out as this?

```
 On hole # 5 a par 5 you shot 5 over par. with a Bo Derek. Bummer.
```

I realize the code doesn't make much sense, as it is not my full program. My problem is when I execute the main function, it prints out as two seperate lines. How can I make it just one line with the input from the two different functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, print ends with a newline character. This call

```
print("Hello World")
```

is in reality used like that by Python :

```
print("Hello World", end='\n')
```

Basically you just need to change the ending :

```
print ('On hole #',hole_number, 'a par',par,'you shot a birdie.', end=' ')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Had to take out a few spaces at the , end=' ' part to make the spacing correct, but that did the trick!

Comment: Does not work for me:  I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" at the end=' ' assignment.